# MariaDB and SqlYog - Can't create database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos6, sqlyog

I had installed mariadb in my vps centOS 6 32bit - after that, i create user with all line but when i had logined with account create ( in SQLyog, i can't create database

```
yum install wget && wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo http://mariadb.if-not-true-then-false.com/rhel/$(rpm -E %rhel)/$(uname -i)/10
yum clean all
yum update
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
service mysql start
chkconfig --levels 150 mysql on
mysql_secure_installation

mysql -u root -p (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18821224/revisions)

CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It reports: I create database in SQLYog - I'm sorry about it, not with command line

> Access denied for user 'username'@'%' to database 'test'

Comment: what you get when you execute :
show grants;

Comment: @@ i receive: Access denied for user 'username'@'%' to database 'test'

Comment: i believe you will need to update mysql password

Comment: How can i do it ? when i run cmd: mysql_secure_installation. I set up password of root- example 123456. Next step, i login with root "mysql -u root -p " with password 123456 and run next cmd

Comment: if you login using that password it works fine?

Comment: You don't understand? I have problems with SQLYog -  i can't create database in SQLYog not with command line

Comment: Assuming you agreed to everything during `mysql_secure_installation` (removed anonymous users, removed the `test` database and access to it), then probably something went wrong with the last command where you grant permissions to `'username'@'%'`; _and_ you have `Database(s): test` in your `SQLYog` connection options. Remove everything from `Database(s)` in connection parameters, it should allow you to connect without a default database, then you'll be able to run `SHOW GRANTS` as suggested above. Or, run it from the cmd client, but specifically as `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'%'`.

Answer (score 0):

The privileges stuff is fickle.

Suggest you add an explicit grant for `test`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'username'@'%';
```